# How to write file in java?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream

I am facing file write issue ,Actually when i run this below code the while loop iterate infinite times.

```
package com.demo.io;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/s.swain/Desktop/loginissue.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/s.swain/Desktop/output.txt");
            int c = in.read();
            while (c != -1) {
                System.out.println(c);
                out.write(c);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can tell me how to write this file.

Thanks

Sitansu

Comment: I'd suggest using Apache Commons IO's `IOUtils.copy(InputStream, OutputStream`.

Comment: Although all answers just suggest to fix the bug in your code; I second the suggestion from Thomas: unless this is for homework/learning; you should not reinvent the wheel. There are libraries that do "file copy" for you; and most likely they are much better tested and will deal with many "cross-plattform" issues that you will not think of.

Comment: or `Files.copy(Paths.get("pathToInputFile"), Paths.get("pathToOutputFile"))`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This conditions *remains `true` for eternity* true because you never update `c` in the `while-loop`:

```
while (c != -1) {
```

Use `in.read` **inside** `while-loop`!

```
int c = in.read();
while (c != -1) {
    System.out.println(c);
    out.write(c);
    c = in.read();
}
```

Comment: I assume you meant: this condition remains true for eternity, once it becomes true.

Answer (score 3):

You missed to read the next byte:

```
int c = in.read();
while (c != -1) {
    System.out.println(c);
    out.write(c);
    c = in.read();//this line added to read next byte
}
```

Or, you can simply use:

```
int c;
while (-1 != (c = in.read())) { /* condition with assignment */
    out.write(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only read `c` once.
Update your while-loop to

```
while (c != -1) {
    System.out.println(c);
    out.write(c);
    c = in.read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
        while(c != null){
            System.out.println(c);
            out.write(c);
            c = reader.readLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
int c = 0;
 while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
 System.out.println((char)c);
 out.write((byte)c);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (c != -1) {
                System.out.println(c);
                out.write(c);
            }
```

what do you think will happen here, if c != -1 ?
You don't update the value of c, so it will cause an infinite loop.